# Как обновлять код Java Spring в запущенном на сервере проекте?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Вопрос достаточно простой. Я недавно только начал изучать спринг и меня интересует как добавлять изменения на сервер:
- Допустим, я написал ClassA.
- Этот класс вместе с остальными классами и файлами в проекте я отправил на сервер. Запустил Jar-проект (Да, и что лучше: war или jar файл?) на сервере.
- Вдруг оказалось, что я недописал какой-то метод в ClassA.
- Вот я дописал метод и теперь надо «обновить проект на сервере».

Вопрос: можно ли это сделать без прерывания нынешнего проекта, запущенного на сервере? Если да, то как.

*P.S. Если мой вопрос не до конца понятен, прошу написать об этом в комментарии. Извините,, заранее, за безграмотность*

Comment: Если кратко, то нельзя. Существующие обходные решения сложны, малоэффективны, а некоторые из них ещё и чертовски опасны.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Как выглядит тогда "правильная последовательсть обновления программы на сервере"?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы ее мне вкратце описать для общего понимания. Я хочу быть уверен в том, что я все делаю правильно

Comment: Смотря что за программа и какой сервер используется.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev обычный вебсайт (онлайн-магазин),  написанный на Spring

Comment: Сервер -  Tomcat

Comment: Тогда надо написать его так, чтобы он поддавался кластеризации и поднять несколько узлов за балансировщиком. В такой схеме не ломающие API обновления можно будет накатывать на узлы по очереди и для пользователей остановка обслуживания будет незаметна. А для  обновлений ломающих нужно ещё городить механизм версий и миграций. Но это не панацея, иногда обслуживание всё-таки придётся останавливать полностью.